# React Native: Back Button Closes Modal

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make a text open a modal when the user pressed on it and closes when they press on the back button. The modal does not open when the user clicks on the text. I tried following the solution from other questions but it doesn't work and their modal are not in a separate component.

Login.js

```
const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);
    return (
        <CustomScrollView>
            <ForgotPassword open={modalOpen}/> //Modal
            <ForgotPasswordText onPress={() => setModalOpen(true)}>Forgot Password?</ForgotPasswordText>
        </CustomScrollView>
    );
```

ForgotPassword.js

```
const ForgotPassword = ({open}) => {
    const [invisible, setInvisible] = useState({open});

    return (
        <Modal 
        statusBarTranslucent 
        transparent= {true} 
        visible={invisible} 
        animationType="fade"
        onRequestClose={() => {setInvisible(!open);}}>
            <CenteredModal>
                <ModalView>
                    <ForgotPasswordTitle>Forgot Password</ForgotPasswordTitle>
                </ModalView>
            </CenteredModal>
        </Modal>
        
    );     
}
```

Comment: “ForgotPasswordText“ share this component as well

Comment: @2xSamurai its just Text component. export const ForgotPasswordText = styled.Text`
    font-size: 16px;
    color: ${purple};
    text-align: center;
    justifyContent: center;
    background-color: ${white};
`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both components are mounted already. If you are changing the `modalOpen` state in your root component, it would not trigger the modal to be opened in the ForgotPassword component in the way it is implemented.

One solution would be to pass the `modalOpen` prop right away and using it in your `Modal` component for the `visible` prop. But you would need to pass your setModalOpen function from your Login component to remain the state, too.

```
const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);
    return (
        <CustomScrollView>
            <ForgotPassword open={modalOpen} setOpen={setModalOpen} /> //Modal
            <ForgotPasswordText onPress={() => setModalOpen(true)}>Forgot Password?</ForgotPasswordText>
        </CustomScrollView>
    );
```

```
const ForgotPassword = ({open, setOpen}) => (
        <Modal 
        statusBarTranslucent 
        transparent={true} 
        visible={open} 
        animationType="fade"
        onRequestClose={() => setOpen(!open)}>
            <CenteredModal>
                <ModalView>
                    <ForgotPasswordTitle>Forgot Password</ForgotPasswordTitle>
                </ModalView>
            </CenteredModal>
        </Modal>
    );
```

Find it working here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-night-lu8e96